# How to handle deeply nested queries when fields can be null depending on logged in or not?

Tags: relayjs

So let's say in React we have `this.props.viewer.parent.child`.
And let's say the response needs to look something like

```
{
  "data": {
    "viewer": {
      "parent": null
    }
  }
}
```

This would create and error in React (`Cannot read property 'child' of null`) because the parent is `null`.

What I have thought of to get around this problem is:

1. use https://www.npmjs.com/package/dot-prop
   whenever using relay data, but just seems like another layer of
   unnecessary complexity.
2. You could check with `if` then render, but that's also
   problematic as you would need to go deep into components and check with 
   a lot of ifs.
3. You could go into the GraphQL schema and add `return null` on every field's resolve. So the response would look like this:

   {
    "data": {
      "viewer": {
         "parent": {
           "child": null
         }
       }
     }
   }

What do you guys do to get around this problem?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I check if any object exists before using it.

`if ( this.props.viewer & this.props.viewer.parent){
  doSomething(this.props.viewer.parent.child);
}`

Answer (score 0):

We use [ramda](http://ramdajs.com/) (in React or wherever we need it in the stack), which is a nice library with functional programming utilities. The one I would use here would be path.

```
import r from 'ramda'

r.path(['viewer', 'parent', 'child'])(this.props) // => value or undefined
```

It stops javascript from crashing whenever something is missing within a nested object.

If you have a look at ramda you will see it is a very powerful library.